# Call scope of functions in a react store

Tags: javascript

I'm not that good with Javascript, so I'm not sure why I can't call the function `dgnProcessesFilter` like this.

```
var conditions = this.dgnProcessesFilter(item.proc_id, "proc_id");
```

The error im getting is `Uncaught TypeError: this.dgnProcessesFilter is not a function`

Just a few line up from that I have the function deceleration.

```
dgnProcessesFilter:function(id, type){
    if(type == "site_id"){
        return  _dgnProceses.filter((process)=>process.site_id==id);
    }
    if(type == "proc_id"){
        return  _dgnProceses.filter((process)=>process.proc_id==id);
    }
},
```

and in another function I also call that function, but with a immediate `RETURN` on the result, and it works just fine.

Why is this, can someone please help me and explain why maybe.

Bellow the call to this function woks fine.

```
getDgnProcesses: function(siteSelector) {
    if(siteSelector.isNaN ){
        if(siteSelector) {
            return this.dgnProcessesFilter(siteSelector, "site_id");
        } else {
            return util.cloneArray(_dgnProceses || []);
        }
    } else {
        if(siteSelector) {

            var selectedSite = this.getSite("description", siteSelector);

            if(selectedSite){
                if (selectedSite.hasOwnProperty("site_id")) {
                    return this.dgnProcessesFilter(selectedSite.site_id, "site_id");
                }
            } else {
                return [];
            }

        } else {
            return util.cloneArray(_dgnProceses || []);
        }
    }
},
```

**update**

the call is from a search component
the store in included

```
_searchDiagnosis: function() {
    this.setState({foundDiagnosis: this.state.searchValue ? DiagnosisStore.getDiagnosisSearch(this.state.searchValue).bind(DiagnosisStore) : [] });
},
```

I just tried the `.bind(DiagnosisStore)`, but it did not seem to do the job.

all the functions are enclosed in the following.

```
var DiagnosisStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {...}
```

Comment: What is the specific error you are getting in the F12 debugging tools when that function executes? Also, what is the value of "this" at that point in time? (Chrome should give you both easily).

Comment: error is: Uncaught TypeError: this.dgnProcessesFilter is not a function

Comment: .this   is equal to  `Window {external: Object, chrome: Object, document: document, ietab: Object, speechSynthesis: SpeechSynthesis…}`    just the first line

Comment: do I need to bind the original function call ( outside the store ) to this store?

Comment: Could you show the context in which you're making the erroneous function call, from the function declaration to the time it is called? It looks like you have the function declared in an object literal (set of {} with "name":"value" properties inside it) - what are you assigning it to? Could you show an abbreviated version of the literal in the context where it is declared?

Comment: OK, thanks for the updates. I'm not going to try to give a full answer because I don't know React, but I do know that `this` no longer works and you need to get an actual reference to the object and replace `this` with it when you call `dgnProcessesFilter`. How to get that reference depends on how React works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are loosing the lexical binding of 'this' at some point. If you are using ES6 or a transpiler (like Babel) try to use the "arrow" function notation to keep the value of 'this' of the surrounding code. 
Here these is a blog post explaining arrow functions https://toddmotto.com/es6-arrow-functions-syntaxes-and-lexical-scoping/

Use also the new ES6 method declaration to be sure that 'this' is the object that contains the method:

```
getDgnProcesses(siteSelector) {

},
```